# boost::asio reading troubles

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I'm new to network programming in general, so please bear with me. I couldn't find anything about this in the boost documentation. When using asio::async_read, an end of file error is raised when there is no data to be read from the socket (at least, I think it does). Is there any way to implement some kind of check to prevent this behavior? What I'm trying to get at is: is there any way to wait for data to be present, and then read said data and call the handler? (If this is poorly worded, please say so. I will try to clarify.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using asio::async_read, an end of
>   file error is raised when there is no
>   data to be read from the socket

`eof` is returned when the other side of the socket is closed, not when there is no data to read.

> What I'm trying to get at is: is there
>   any way to wait for data to be
>   present, and then read said data and
>   call the handler?

This is called polling, it's what the asio `io_service` does for you. You tell the `io_service` that you want to read data from the socket by initiating an `async_read`. It performs the read on your behalf and invokes the completion handler when it is finished successfully or unsuccessfully.

It might be worth your time to [study the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282659/some-clarification-needed-about-synchronous-versus-asynchronous-asio-operations/5291002#5291002) between asynchronous and synchronous methods offered by Boost.Asio.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Guess it was a problem in my client instead of my server.