# How game servers with Boost:Asio work asynchronously?

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to create a game server, and currently, I am making it with threads. Every object( a player , monster ), has its own thread with while(1) cycle , in witch particular functions are performed.

And the server basically works like this:

```
main(){

//some initialization

while(1)
{
//reads clients packet
//directs packet info to a particular object
//object performs some functions
//then server returns result packet back to client
Sleep(1);
}
```

I have heard that is not efficient to make the server using threads like that,
and I should consider to use Boost::Asio, and make the functions work asynchronously.
But I don't know how then the server would work. I would be grateful if someone would explain how basically such servers work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Every object( a player , monster ), has its own thread. 
>   I have heard that is not efficient to make the server using threads
>   like that

You are correct, this is not a scalable design. Consider a large game where you may have 10,000 objects or even a million. Such a design quickly falls apart when you require a thread per object. This is known as the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

> I should consider to use Boost::Asio, and make the functions work
>   asynchronously. But I don't know how then the server would work.
>   I would be grateful if someone would explain how basically such 
>   servers work.

You should start by following the Boost::Asio [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html), and pay specific attention to the [Asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime3). The [concept of asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291002/283302) programming compared to synchronous programming is not difficult after you understand that the flow of your program is inverted. From a high level, your game server will have an event loop that is driven by a `boost::asio::io_service`. Overly simplified, it will look like this

```
int
main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    // add some work to the io_service

    io_service.run(); // start event loop

    // should never get here
}
```

The callback handlers that are invoked from the event loop will chain operations together. That is, once your callback for reading data from a client is invoked, the handler will initiate another asynchronous operation.

The beauty of this design is that it decouples threading from concurrency. Consider a long running operation in your game server, such as reading data from a client. Using asynchronous methods, your game server does not need to wait for the operation to complete. It will be notified when the operation has completed on behalf of the kernel.