# Boost asio server

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Regarding the answer on: [How game servers with Boost:Asio work asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718633/how-game-servers-with-boostasio-work-asynchronously)

What if I have a server which does calculations and at the same time sends/receive packets from clients?

I mean if I was coding a http-server the example on the answer would suffice since all the data sent are functions of the data received.

Assume my program calculates values and needs to update clients according to their needs (some may want update frequency 1 hz, where another one 10 hz etc).

This kind of structure would be very helpful to me:

```
while(1){
pollNetworking(); //<- my function
value1 += 5; value2 = random();
}
```

In my pollNetworking function I was thinking of calling something like acceptor.accept(*socket,10); where 10 is the timeout in milliseconds but since there is no timeout parameter I don't know how to structure this.

Scalability is not the biggest issue, can I spawn a thread per socket,an extra thread for accepting and another one for calculations? Will this be easy to implement? Because I want this to be as stable as possible, then comes speed, then comes scalability. And when it comes to multi-threading I don't trust myself that I can code&debug it cleanly yet.

Edit: I learned that I can use io_service::poll, which only dispatch ready events without blocking. So it is a synchronous function with 0 timeout, exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can do calculations at the same time as data is being sent and received from the client.  However, the buffers and socket will likely need to be protected from concurrency access.

For most Boost.Asio operations, portable timeout functionality is only possible on asynchronous actions.  This requires issuing an async operation on an entity, setting a timer, then waiting.  For an example of canceling `async_read` with a timeout, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10858719/) question.

The simplest, and less scalable, approach is to designate a thread per responsibility (thread per socket, accepting, and calculations).  Synchronization will likely need to occur, such as protecting calculation results.  For example, if `value1` and `value2` are only meaningful in the same iteration, then socket threads need to guarantee that the values are written together without the calculation thread changing the values mid-write.  Various synchronization constructs, such as those provided by [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), can be used to accomplish this.  Also, it may be easier to implement and debug by minimizing the amount of asynchronous calls being used.

For a much scalable approach, most of the program will be written as a series of handlers invoked from asynchronous operations.  This allows for the program to take advantage of threads and thread pools much easier.  However, it can scatter program logic across numerous functions, and can quickly become difficult to follow.  Often times, programs written with asynchronous actions in mind will perform synchronization with [`boost::asio::strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html), and manage object lifetimes through [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

The ease of implementation will depend on experience.  Keep in mind that network programming, concurrency, and asynchronous operations are innately difficult.  There is rarely solution that is both simple and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have asynchronous accept and receive, but send to the clients synchronous whenever you need to send to them.

If you can use separate threads for each connected client (I'm guessing you won't be expecting hundreds or thousands of connections) then you can use one thread per connected client for both calculations and sending, while keeping the receiving asynchronous.