# Role of io_service in TCP/IP sockets - Need Help understanding

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am having difficulty understanding the role of io_service when it comes to TCP/IP sockets. Here is my basic understanding of io_service. The `io_service->run()` blocks and accepts work requests (We use the `io_service::work`) to `post` or `dispatch` work to the `io_service`. Am I correct here? Please let me know if I am missing anything? Now following is my code for a simple server

```
void RunServer()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(new boost::asio::io_service);
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor > acceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor( *io_service ));
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket > sock( new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket( *io_service ) );

    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver( *io_service );
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( "127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( 7777 ));
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve( query );
        acceptor->open( endpoint.protocol() );
        acceptor->set_option( boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( false ) );
        acceptor->bind( endpoint );
        acceptor->listen( boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections );
        acceptor->async_accept( *sock, boost::bind( OnAccept, _1, sock ) );//Receives only one connection
        std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections \n";
        io_service->run();  //Confusion here --- Line A
    }
    catch( std::exception & ex )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "] Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

Now I know that incase there is no work object attached to io_service the method `io_service->run()` will never block, correct? Now my question here is what role does `io_service->run()` play above. From experimentation I realized that if I remove the code the `OnAccept` method is not called. Also where is the work being added to the `io_service` here. What exactly is happening here? Any explanation that clarifies this would be appreciated.

Comment: The "work" added to the io_service is the acceptor: you create it by passing the io_service to its constructor and when you call async_accept it posts work to the io_service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your simple server code looks fine. An `io_service` is just that, it services I/O operations. It would be useful to study the Asio [anatomy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html) to better understand its role for asynchronous operations

[image: asynchronous connect]

You do not need an [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object to prevent `io_service::run()` from returning immediately. In your case, you have given the `io_service` work to do with `async_accept()`, and presumably more work do to in `OnAccept()` with another `async_accept()` call.

There are several other useful [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291002/283302) for similar questions on SO as well that you may find helpful.