# Confused when boost::asio::io_service run method blocks/unblocks

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Being a total beginner to Boost.Asio, I am confused with [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html).  I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me when this method blocks/unblocks. The documentations states:

> The `run()` function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the `io_service` has been stopped.
>
> Multiple threads may call the `run()` function to set up a pool of threads from which the `io_service` may execute handlers. All threads that are waiting in the pool are equivalent and the `io_service` may choose any one of them to invoke a handler.
>
> A normal exit from the `run()` function implies that the `io_service` object is stopped (the `stopped()` function returns true). Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately unless there is a prior call to `reset()`.

What does the following statement mean?

> [...] no more handlers to be dispatched [...]

---

While trying to understand the behavior of `io_service::run()`, I came across this [example](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/?pg=4) (example 3a).  Within it, I observe that `io_service->run()` blocks and waits for work orders.

```
// WorkerThread invines io_service->run()
void WorkerThread(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service);
void CalculateFib(size_t);

boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service(
    new boost::asio::io_service);
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(
   new boost::asio::io_service::work(*io_service));

// ...

boost::thread_group worker_threads;
for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
{
  worker_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&WorkerThread, io_service));
}

io_service->post( boost::bind(CalculateFib, 3));
io_service->post( boost::bind(CalculateFib, 4));
io_service->post( boost::bind(CalculateFib, 5));

work.reset();
worker_threads.join_all();
```

However, in the following code that I was working on, the client connects using TCP/IP and the run method blocks until data is asynchronously received.

```
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp tcp;
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service(
    new boost::asio::io_service);
boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket(new tcp::socket(*io_service));

// Connect to 127.0.0.1:9100.
tcp::resolver resolver(*io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", 
                           boost::lexical_cast< std::string >(9100));
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
socket->connect(endpoint_iterator->endpoint());

// Just blocks here until a message is received.
socket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_client, 3000), 0,
                      ClientReceiveEvent);
io_service->run();

// Write response.
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
std::cout << "Sending message \n";
boost::asio::write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer("some data"), ignored_error);
```

Any explanation of `run()` that describes its behavior in the two examples below would be appreciated.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

### Foundation

Lets start with a simplified example and examine the relevant Boost.Asio pieces:

```
void handle_async_receive(...) { ... }
void print() { ... }

...  

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

...

io_service.post(&print);                             // 1
socket.connect(endpoint);                            // 2
socket.async_receive(buffer, &handle_async_receive); // 3
io_service.post(&print);                             // 4
io_service.run();                                    // 5
```

#### What Is A *Handler*?

A *handler* is nothing more than a callback.  In the example code, there are 3 handlers:

- The `print` handler (1).
- The `handle_async_receive` handler (3).
- The `print` handler (4).

Even though the same `print()` function is used twice, each use is considered to create its own uniquely identifiable handler.  Handlers can come in many shapes and sizes, ranging from basic functions like the ones above to more complex constructs such as functors generated from `boost::bind()` and lambdas.  Regardless of the complexity, the handler still remains nothing more than a callback.

#### What Is *Work*?

Work is some processing that Boost.Asio has been requested to do on behalf of the application code.  Sometimes Boost.Asio may start some of the work as soon as it has been told about it, and other times it may wait to do the work at a later point in time.  Once it has finished the work, Boost.Asio will inform the application by invoking the supplied *handler*.

Boost.Asio guarantees that *handlers* will only run within a thread that is currently calling `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()`.  These are the threads that will do work and call *handlers*.  Therefore, in above example, `print()` is not invoked when it is posted into the `io_service` (1).  Instead, it is added to the `io_service` and will be invoked at a later point in time.  In this case, it within `io_service.run()` (5).

#### What Are Asynchronous Operations?

An [asynchronous operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) creates work and Boost.Asio will invoke a *handler* to inform the application when the work has completed.  Asynchronous operations are created by calling a function that has a name with the prefix `async_`. These functions are also known as *initiating functions*.

Asynchronous operations can be decomposed into three unique steps:

- Initiating, or informing, the associated `io_service` that works needs to be done.  The `async_receive` operation (3) informs the `io_service` that it will need to asynchronously read data from the socket, then `async_receive` returns immediately.
- Doing the actual work.  In this case, when `socket` receives data, bytes will be read and copied into `buffer`.  The actual work will be done in either:

  - The initiating function (3), if Boost.Asio can determine that it will not block.
  - When the application explicitly run the `io_service` (5).
- Invoking the `handle_async_receive` [ReadHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html).  Once again, *handlers* are only invoked within threads running the `io_service`.  Thus, regardless of when the work is done (3 or 5), it is guaranteed that `handle_async_receive()` will only be invoked within `io_service.run()` (5).

The separation in time and space between these three steps is known as control flow inversion.  It is one of the complexities that makes asynchronous programming difficult.  However, there are techniques that can help mitigate this, such as by using [coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html).

#### What Does `io_service.run()` Do?

When a thread calls `io_service.run()`, work and *handlers* will be invoked from within this thread.  In the above example, `io_service.run()` (5) will block until either:

- It has invoked and returned from both `print` handlers, the receive operation completes with success or failure, and its `handle_async_receive` handler has been invoked and returned.
- The `io_service` is explicitly stopped via [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html).
- An exception is thrown from within a handler.

One potential psuedo-ish flow could be described as the following:

```
create io_service
create socket
add print handler to io_service (1)
wait for socket to connect (2)
add an asynchronous read work request to the io_service (3)
add print handler to io_service (4)
run the io_service (5)
  is there work or handlers?
    yes, there is 1 work and 2 handlers
      does socket have data? no, do nothing
      run print handler (1)
  is there work or handlers?
    yes, there is 1 work and 1 handler
      does socket have data? no, do nothing
      run print handler (4)
  is there work or handlers?
    yes, there is 1 work
      does socket have data? no, continue waiting
  -- socket receives data --
      socket has data, read it into buffer
      add handle_async_receive handler to io_service
  is there work or handlers?
    yes, there is 1 handler
      run handle_async_receive handler (3)
  is there work or handlers?
    no, set io_service as stopped and return
```

Notice how when the read finished, it added another *handler* to the `io_service`.  This subtle detail is an important feature of asynchronous programming.  It allows for *handlers* to be chained together.  For instance, if `handle_async_receive` did not get all the data it expected, then its implementation could post another asynchronous read operation, resulting in `io_service` having more work, and thus not returning from `io_service.run()`.

Do note that when the `io_service` has ran out of work, the application must [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) the `io_service` before running it again.

---

### Example Question and Example 3a code

Now, lets examine the two pieces of code referenced in the question.

#### Question Code

`socket->async_receive` adds work to the `io_service`.  Thus, `io_service->run()` will block until the read operation completes with success or error, and `ClientReceiveEvent` has either finished running or throws an exception.

#### [Example 3a](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/?pg=4) Code

In hopes of making it easier to understand, here is a smaller annotated Example 3a:

```
void CalculateFib(std::size_t n);

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work =       // '. 1
      boost::in_place(boost::ref(io_service));                // .'

  boost::thread_group worker_threads;                         // -.
  for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)                                  //   :
  {                                                           //   '.
    worker_threads.create_thread(                             //     :- 2
      boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) //   .'
    );                                                        //   :
  }                                                           // -'

  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 3));              // '.
  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 4));              //   :- 3
  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 5));              // .'

  work = boost::none;                                         // 4
  worker_threads.join_all();                                  // 5
}
```

At a high-level, the program will create 2 threads that will process the `io_service`'s event loop (2).  This results in a simple thread pool that will calculate Fibonacci numbers (3).

The one major difference between the Question Code and this code is that this code invokes `io_service::run()` (2) *before* actual work and handlers are added to the `io_service` (3).  To prevent the `io_service::run()` from returning immediately, an [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object is created (1).  This object prevents the `io_service` from running out of work; therefore, `io_service::run()` will not return as a result of no work.

The overall flow is as follows:

1. Create and add the `io_service::work` object added to the `io_service`.
2. Thread pool created that invokes `io_service::run()`.  These worker threads will not return from `io_service` because of the `io_service::work` object.
3. Add 3 handlers that calculate Fibonacci numbers to the `io_service`, and return immediately.  The worker threads, not the main thread, may start running these handlers immediately.
4. Delete the `io_service::work` object.
5. Wait for worker threads to finish running.  This will only occur once all 3 handlers have finished execution, as the `io_service` neither has handlers nor work.

The code could be written differently, in the same manner as the Original Code, where handlers are added to the `io_service`, and then the `io_service` event loop is processed.  This removes the need to use `io_service::work`, and results in the following code:

```
int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 3));              // '.
  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 4));              //   :- 3
  io_service.post(boost::bind(CalculateFib, 5));              // .'

  boost::thread_group worker_threads;                         // -.
  for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)                                  //   :
  {                                                           //   '.
    worker_threads.create_thread(                             //     :- 2
      boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) //   .'
    );                                                        //   :
  }                                                           // -'
  worker_threads.join_all();                                  // 5
}
```

---

### Synchronous vs. Asynchronous

Although the code in the question is using an asynchronous operation, it is effectively functioning synchronously, as it is waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete:

```
socket.async_receive(buffer, handler)
io_service.run();
```

is equivalent to:

```
boost::asio::error_code error;
std::size_t bytes_transferred = socket.receive(buffer, 0, error);
handler(error, bytes_transferred);
```

As a general rule of thumb, try to avoid mixing synchronous and asynchronous operations.  Often times, it can turn a complex system into a complicated system.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291002/1053968) highlights advantages of asynchronous programming, some of which are also covered in the Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html).

Comment: Awesome post. I would like to add just one thing because i feel it gets not enough attention: After run() has returned you need to call reset() on your io_service before you can run() it again. Otherwise it may return instantly whether or not there are async_ operations waiting or not.

Comment: Where does buffer come from? What is it?

Comment: I am still confused.  If mixing is sync and async is not recommended, then what is the pure async mode? can you give an example showing the code without io_service.run();?

Comment: @Splash One can use [`io_service.poll()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html) to process the event loop without blocking on outstanding operations. The primary recommendation to avoid mixing synchronous and asynchronous operations is to avoid adding unnecessary complexity, and to prevent poor responsiveness when handlers take a long time to complete. There are some cases where it is safe, such as when one knows the synchronous operation will not block.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently"  in *"Boost.Asio guarantees that handlers will only run **within a thread that is currently calling `run()`**...."*? If there are N threads (which has called `run()`), then which one is "current" thread?  There can be many? Or do you mean the thread which has finished executing the `async_*()` (say `async_read`), is *guaranteed* to call its handlers as well?

Comment: ....  Also, what if I call another `async_*` function from such handler? Will *this* `async_*` be executed in the *same* thread? (If so, then I'm wondering as to what is the point of using `async_*` in this case, as it behaves like *sync* anyway.. and what if I call more than one `async_*` functions from such handler?).

Comment: @Nawaz When work is posted to the `io_service`, any thread that is blocked on `io_service.run()` can be selected to perform the work.  It is unspecified as to which thread will run perform which work.  Hence, if a thread that has `io_service::run()` in its callstack initiates an `async_read()` operation, then this thread and other threads blocked on `io_service.run()` may be selected to run any of the work needed for the operation and the completion handler. It is very common to chain operations together by initiating an async operations from within the completion handlers of other operations.

Comment: Can you explain why you pass boost::in_place(boost::ref(io_service)) instead of just io_service to the work constructor in Example 3a?

Comment: @shadow_map this is a boost optional in-place construction idiom - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185673/avoiding-temporary-when-using-boostoptional

Comment: I don't get it. What is the point of async operation if you must call the ``ìo_service::run()``` to start to async operation and it is gonna block your current thread anyways?

Comment: @TannerSansbury Which thread receives the socket data?

Comment: small gem, the `io_service` can be explicitly stopped via `io_service::stop()`

Comment: If I need an extra thread to run a completion handler, because I'm blocking on a function in that handler, and the function that blocks uses a strand for accessing a shared resource (therefore I must avoid that the completion handler runs on the same strand). Can I use a thread_pool with  bind_executor(thread_pool, handler)? And the thread pool will just execute the handler for me, without using `io_context.run()` for having that handler executed?

Comment: Or is it sufficient If I just create a second strand and ensure that enough threads are calling run() ? The docs say that strands do  not guarantee parallel execution, so  I worry that  this might not be enough!

Answer (score 23):

To simplify how what `run` does, think of it as an employee that must process a pile of paper; it takes one sheet, does what the sheet tells, throws the sheet away and takes the next one; when he runs out of sheets, it leaves the office. On each sheet there can be any kind of instruction, even adding a new sheet to the pile.
Back to asio: you can give to an `io_service` work in two ways, essentially: by using `post` on it as in the sample you linked, or by using other objects that internally call `post` on the `io_service`, like the `socket` and its `async_*` methods.