# Boost::asio::async_write, handler called only once

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am quite new in boost::asio and I have a problem. I am writting client that sends in loop some commands to server. I am sending command with boost::asio::async_write and I expect that every time I send commands handler will be called. In fact only during first sending I see that handler is called. My client looks like that:

```
Client::Client(boost::asio::io_service & p_ioService,
           boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint p_endpoint)
 : io_service(p_ioService), endpoint(p_endpoint), socket(p_ioService)
{
   socket.connect(endpoint); 
}
Client::~Client()
{
    socket.close();
}
void Client::sendCommand(const string & p_command)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket,boost::asio::buffer(p_command), 
                              boost::bind(&Client::onSendingFinished,this, _1, _2));
    io_service.run();
}
void Client::onSendingFinished(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t    bytes_transferred)
{
    cout<<"Sent "<<bytes_transferred<<endl;
}
```

There is no other place in main.cpp where io_service.run is called. I notice that if I call
    io_service.reset() after io_service.run() it works fine, handler is called every time.

How should I solve this without io_service.reset()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the aversion to calling [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html).  In this case, it is necessary to invoke prior to any subsequent calls to `io_service::run()`:

> `reset()` must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the `io_service` being stopped or running out of work.

It is possible that a thread returns from `run()` as a result of an exception being thrown, yet the `io_service` has neither been stopped nor ran out of work.  In this case, the thread can invoke `run()` without calling `reset()`.

---

The current `Client::sendCommand()` is synchronous.  It is an implementation detail that it initiates an asynchronous operation, then blocks in `io_service::run()` waiting for the operation to complete.  Unless there are multiple threads invoking commands on `socket`, multiple threads running the `io_service`, or the write operation needs to be cancellable, such as from a timeout, then it would be functionally equivalent and possible easier to implement `Client::sendCommand()` with a synchronous [`write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload2.html).

```cpp
void Client::sendCommand(const string & p_command)
{
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  std::size_t bytes_transferred =
      boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(p_command), ec);
  onSendingFinished(ec, bytes_transferred);
}
```

If `Client::sendCommand()` needs to be asynchronous, then:

- The `io_service` should be ran from outside of `Client::sendCommand()`.  If the `io_service` does not always have outstanding work, then [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) can be used control when `run()` returns.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575732/1053968) answer for more details as to when `io_service::run()` blocks and unblocks.
- The underlying memory provided to [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) as the buffer (`p_command`) needs to remain valid until the operation's handler, `Client::onSendingFinished()`, has been called.  In this case, it may require making a copy of `p_command` in `Client::sendCommand()`, writing the copy to the socket, then deleting the copy from within the handler.

  > [...] ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not inherently bad to call `reset()` every now and then, there are two typical ways to avoid having to do it.

1. Start a new async operation within the handler of the first one. `run()` only returns once all handlers have finished and thus a new async operation started in a handler is still in time to keep blocking `io_service`.
2. Use `io_service::work`. If you create an instance of `io_service::work` constructed with your `io_service` as parameter, than your subsequent calls to `run()` will not return as long as the `work` object remains alive. And thus you will not have to reset anything. Of course this means that either one of your handlers or another thread has to destroy the `work` object at some time, if you want `run()` to ever stop blocking.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unusual to *just* send messages, it's far more common to have two way communication.

If you implemented a receiver as well, then your receive code would always require a receive handler running in the `io_service` and you wouldn't have this problem...