# Boost threadpool using asio: Threads randomly don't execute

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm using a threadpool based on `boost::asio::ioService`. However, threads sometimes don't  execute the work posted to the ioService.

I built the following minimal example to investigate this:

```cpp
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "threadpool.h"

int fib(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1) return 1;
    return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);
}

void doSomething(int value)
{
  std::cout << "doSomething(): " << fib(value) << std::endl;
}

void doSomethingElse(int value)
{
  std::cout << "doSomethingElse(): " << value+value << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // create asio ioservice and threadgroup for the pool
  boost::asio::io_service ioService;
  boost::thread_group threadpool;

  // Add worker threads to threadpool
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    threadpool.create_thread(
      boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));  
  }

  // post work to the ioservice
  ioService.post(boost::bind(doSomething, 40));
  ioService.post(boost::bind(doSomethingElse, 3));

  // run the tasks and return, if all queued work is finished
  ioService.run();

  // join all threads of the group
  threadpool.join_all();
}
```

If I run this in a loop like so:

```
while true; do echo "--------------"; ./boost_threadpool_test; done
```

I will get output similar to this:

```
--------------
doSomething(): 102334155
doSomethingElse(): 6
--------------
--------------
--------------
--------------
doSomething(): 102334155
doSomethingElse(): 6
--------------
--------------
--------------
doSomething(): 102334155
doSomethingElse(): 6
--------------
--------------
doSomething(): 102334155
doSomethingElse(): 6
--------------
--------------
--------------
--------------
--------------
--------------
doSomething(): 102334155
doSomethingElse(): 6
--------------
```

So 2 or more consecutive lines show that the threads have not processed their work.
I also tried my own implementation of a threadpool just using boost threadgroup to cut out the IOService, but with similar results.
Is there some basic thing I'm getting wrong here?

BTW: I'm on Boost 1.46.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `io_service::run()`, but don't give [any work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) to the `io_service`, so `run()` [just exits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html). Now you have to call `io_service::reset()` before any subsequent `run()`.

The fact that it works sometimes is due to the race condition: `ioService.post(boost::bind(doSomething, 40))` might execute in the main thread a moment before the thread(s) in your pool get started, thus giving the `io_service` some job.

Answer (score 1):

You should read, and read again, [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568100/confused-when-boostasioio-service-run-method-blocks-unblocks?rq=1) from [Tanner Sansbury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053968/tanner-sansbury), he is an asio boss !

asio is not so complicated, but only once that this basic behavior is fully understood.

Welcome in the wonderful world of asio !