# Avoiding temporary when using boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

boost::optional support in_place construction like so:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/typed_in_place_factory.hpp>

class Foo
{
    int a,b;

  public:
    Foo(int one, int two) : a(one),b(two) {}
};


int main()
{
    boost::optional<Foo> fooOpt(boost::in_place<Foo>(1,3));
}
```

Once we have an initialized fooOpt, is there a way of assigning a new Foo to it without creating a temporary?

Something like :

```
fooOpt = boost::in_place<Foo>(1,3);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

### boost::optional

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::optional<int> x;
    x = boost::in_place(3);
}
```

We can also show (via code) that this is building the object in-place by making `Foo` inherit from `boost::noncopyable`:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

class Foo : boost::noncopyable {
    public:
        Foo(int one, int two) {}
};


int main() {
    boost::optional<Foo> x;
    x = boost::in_place(3, 4);
}
```

### std::optional (eventually...)

Eventually, we will get access to `std::optional`. This type will implement an `emplace()` method, that will implement in-place construction as well.

```
#include <optional>

int main() {
    std::optional<int> x;
    x.emplace(3);
}
```

### boost::optional (soon...)

In version 1.56.0, `boost::optional` will also implement the `emplace()` method that I talked about for std::optional. So, let's see that:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::optional<int> x;
    x.emplace(3);
}
```

Comment: The first constructs a temporary `boost::optional<int>` in-place, then assigns it to `x` -- [I see no `operator=` overload for `boost::in_place`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html) in the docs.

Comment: @Yakk There's one under the [Synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/synopsis.html) page. Perhaps that's a documentation bug. `template<class InPlaceFactory> optional& operator=(InPlaceFactory const& f);`

Comment: @Yakk: And how can we assign it to `x` if it's noncopyable.

Comment: Hmm.  [Source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) has `#if !defined(BOOST_OPTIONAL_NO_INPLACE_FACTORY_SUPPORT) && !defined(BOOST_OPTIONAL_WEAK_OVERLOAD_RESOLUTION)` then `template<class Expr>
    optional& operator= ( Expr const& expr )`, which `assign_expr`, which `construct` or `assign_expr_to_initialized`, the second of which `destroy`s then `construct`s.

Comment: Wow, be careful about passing a typed `in_place` that does not match `T` -- it will blindly blow things up!

Comment: @Yakk: The examples that I've tried all provide compiler errors. What are you doing that "blows things up"?

Comment: I haven't run it but: `typed_in_place_factory_base` seems to be applied to `m_storage.address()` (a `void*`) without any type checking?  So `boost::optional<int>() = boost::in_place<double>(3.0)` may construct a 64 bit `double` at the address of the `int`?

Comment: @Yakk: That's not doing what you think it's doing (and what I was thinking it was doing for the last 20 minutes). You're creating an `in_place_factory` that has the first argument specified as a double. So that will call the `in_place_factory` code within optional, and simple cast the `(double) 3.0` to an int. Which is fine. Now I'm just confused as to how we're supposed to created `typed_in_place_factory`s at all.

Comment: @Yakk: But that being said, this causes a segmentation fault: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4949fb4e2d3e4abe

Comment: @Yakk: And, for whatever reason, boost::optional doesn't by default include the typed_in_place_factory header. So if we do include it, your code produces an `error: call to 'in_place' is ambiguous`. But either way, you are correct that the `typed_in_place_factory` is exceptionally dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The documented interface does not support this.

However, if you know that nobody extends `boost::optional`, I believe this may be technically valid:

```
template<typename T, typename... Us>
void emplace_replace( boost::optional<T>& target, Us&&... us ) {
  target.~boost::optional<T>();
  try {
    new (&target) boost::optional<T>( boost::in_place( std::forward<Us>(us)...) );
  } catch(...) {
    new (&target) boost::optional<T>();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Here, we destroy the `target`, then reconstruct a new `boost::optional<T>` in its place with in-place construction.  The `try`-`catch` construct should make most `throw`s during construction safe: if it throws, you end up with an empty `optional`.

This naturally behaves differently than `operator=` is expected to.

---

In 1.55 (and maybe earlier?), there is an undocumented `operator=` that takes an `Expr` which supports `boost::in_place` and `boost::in_place<T>`.  See @sharth's answer for a detailed use.

My quick reading indicates that a **typed** inplace factory via this method may have insufficient guards:

```
boost::optional<int> test;
// test = boost::in_place<double>( 3 ); // <-- very dangerous
test = boost::in_place( 3 ); // safe
test = boost::in_place( 3.0 ); // safe
```

If a type is passed directly to `in_place<?>`, it can generate a `typed_in_place_factory`, which are dangerous (they make the passed in type, and don't check that it is compatible).  So don't pass any types to `boost::in_place`.

This (from reading the source) does something similar to my destroy/reconstruct code, except it does it without destroying the entire `optional` and just destroys the stored data and makes it uninitialized.

---

In boost 1.56b1, [emplace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0_b1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_emplace) has been added to `boost::optional`.  It does something similar to both of the above operations.  (via @AkiraTakahashi)

---

`std::optional` proposals I have seen have included a member function `.emplace( Us&&... )` that supports emplace replacing directly.

Comment: You could take the boost::optional by template argument type sfinae it to only accept boost::optional. In addition you could assert the typeid in debug builds.

Comment: Hmm.. What happen if an exception fires during that code?

Comment: @sharth Fixed, with conditions.

Comment: As additional information, In Boost 1.56.0, `boost::optional` will supports `emplace`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0_b1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_emplace

Answer (score 0):

Once you know it's there, you could create an ordinary reference:

```
optional<Foo> optFoo = ....;
Foo &foo = *optFoo;
foo.x = 3;
foofun(foo);
foo = Foo();
```