# ‘acceptor’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio::ip::udp’ while migration from tcp to udp

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp, boost-asio

I have tcp socket.
Here is how it was looks on one side:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

tcp::socket socket(service);
tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
acceptor.accept(socket_);

// send something
socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(&(*sbBuf.begin()), len));
```

And on another side:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

tcp::socket socket(service);
tcp::resolver resolver(service);
tcp::resolver::query query2(udp::v4(), host, portStr);
tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::connect(socket , iterator);
//receive something
size_t len = socket.receive(boost::asio::buffer((void *)&(*(v.begin())), DEFAULT_BUFLEN));
```

Now I need to change `tcp` to `udp`.
I change all `boost::asio::ip::tcp::` prefix to `boost::asio::ip::udp::`.
I use `send` instead of `write_some`.

Now I stuck with next error `‘acceptor’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio::ip::udp’`

I tried to found some examples but I can't find good one to understand what I can use instead of `acceptor`

Comment: It's hard to accept things that will not exist. UDP is connectionless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing such as an acceptor for UDP, read about the difference between UDP and TCP connection. Or/and see [UDP communication using c++ boost asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273599/udp-communication-using-c-boost-asio)

Also [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/protocols.html) is an nice summary