# How to empty the task pool in boost asio service?

Tags: boost-asio

One can add task with post() but how to clear all the pool in the io_service? (so it stops processing any task and clears the pool)

Comment: This very detailed answer may help: [Confused when boost::asio::io_service run method blocks/unblocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568100/confused-when-boostasioio-service-run-method-blocks-unblocks).

Answer (score 1):

The linked answer has all the details: [Confused when boost::asio::io_service run method blocks/unblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568100/confused-when-boostasioio-service-run-method-blocks-unblocks)

The short story: `stop()` stops processing tasks from the queue(s) (any handlers are not interrupted of course).

`reset()` prepares the `io_service` for re-use.

Comment: @mimosa11 Read carefully this answer, again and again until you really understand it, and so you will learn easily asio, one of the most valuable libraries.