# simple async send to tcp socket

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, tcp

I have a code like this:

```
while (!isNeedStop) {
  char * data; int len;
  getData(data, &len);
  send(sock, data, len, 0);
}
```

`getData` produce some data, about 3-5 kb. The profiler shows, that getData and send takes the same time and I want to send data asynchronously - when `getData` gets next piece of data, `send` sends previous.

I can write a code with additional thread + queue. But maybe Visual Studio alredy has good class for it?

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331869/what-are-async-sockets

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx